# SAGE + right_kernel() + basis matrix

Tags: sage

I executed the right_kernel() instruction for any binary matrix H. Why always I get a basis matrix in this form [I|A] (Where I:identity matrix)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it is not the case that the basis matrix has the form `[I|A]`.

According to the sage [documentation](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/matrix2.html#sage.matrix.matrix2.Matrix.right_kernel) the basis matrix is in echelon form by default.

For example

```
sage: H
[1 0 0 1 1]
[1 0 1 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0]
sage: H.right_kernel()
Vector space of degree 5 and dimension 2 over Finite Field of size 2
Basis matrix:
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 1 1 1]
```